Java native method implementation problem
Following is the Java code:
 // Java Program to Illustrate Native Keyword // Inside DLL named:
 NameOfDLLFile
 
 // Main class // NativeDemo // Java Program to Illustrate Native
 Keyword
 
 class NaitiveDemo {
     // Native method declaration
     public native void test();
 
 // Load the native library
 /*static {
     System.loadLibrary("NaitiveDemo"); // Load the DLL or shared library
 }*/    static{

 try {
     System.loadLibrary("NaitiveDemo");
 } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
     System.err.println("Error loading native library: " + e.getMessage());
 } }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     NaitiveDemo obj = new NaitiveDemo();
     obj.test(); // Call the native method
 } }

And following is C++ code for test method implementation:
// C++ Program to Be Shared In DLL to Illustrate
// Native Method in Java

// Importing required libraries
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
// Method 2
// Native
void test(int var) { cout << var; }

// Method 1
// Main driver method
int main()
{

    test(10);

    return 1;
}

Both codes above have compiled successfully.
I am able to see following directory listing:
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        25-07-2024     11:09                .vscode
-a----        25-07-2024     11:26           1161 NaitiveDemo.class
-a----        25-07-2024     09:37            301 NaitiveDemo.cpp
-a----        25-07-2024     11:10         106823 NaitiveDemo.dll
-a----        25-07-2024     10:59            736 NaitiveDemo.java
-a----        25-07-2024     10:50            462 NativeDemo.class

I am using Windows 11 64 bit. The execution of code gives me an error.
Execution of code:
PS C:\Users\pcuser\23 july 2024\theory\NaitiveDemo> java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\pcuser\23 july 2024\theory\NaitiveDemo" NaitiveDemo

The error:
Error: Could not find or load main class .library.path=C:\Users\pcuser\23 july 2024\theory\NaitiveDemo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /library/path=C:\Users\pcuser\23 july 2024\theory\NaitiveDemo
PS C:\Users\pcuser\23 july 2024\theory\NaitiveDemo

Java version:
java --version
openjdk 17.0.12 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.12+7 (build 17.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.12+7 (build 17.0.12+7, mixed mode, sharing)

What could be the problem?
based on the response below I execute this as
PS C:\Users\pcuser\23 july 2024\theory\NaitiveDemo> java '-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\pcuser\23 july 2024\theory\NaitiveDemo' NaitiveDemo
Now I am getting error
 NaitiveDemo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void NaitiveDemo.test()'
        at NaitiveDemo.test(Native Method)
        at NaitiveDemo.main(NaitiveDemo.java:27)

my question is not about execution of code in powershell it is about problem in the lines of code as why the program is not able to load NaitiveDemo library that is created in folder where I am doing this program.

When using PowerShell to run Java and trying to pass arguments like -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\pcuser\23 july 2024\theory\NaitiveDemo" you trigger a bug in PowerShell (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6291). The workaround is to quote the complete parameter: java "-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\pcuser\23 july 2024\theory\NaitiveDemo" NaitiveDemo

thanks I tried but still I got the error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void NaitiveDemo.test()'         at NaitiveDemo.test(Native Method)         at NaitiveDemo.main(NaitiveDemo.java:27)

If you can start the Java class you will notice the next problem: your void test(int var) function in NaitiveDemo.cpp is not a valid implementation for the public native void test(); method. If you execute javac -h . NaitiveDemo.java the Java compiler will generate a header file (NaitiveDemo.h) that contains the expected method name and signature for the C++ function: JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NaitiveDemo_test(JNIEnv *, jobject);

it gives me error javac -h NaitiveDemo.java error: no source files

You left out -h's value which is one dot: javac -h    .    NaitiveDemo.java

thanks for pointing that out about -h . I  compiled the code it gave no error when I execute javac -h . NaitiveDemo.java but the program is not executing i.e. giving errors in execution java NaitiveDemo Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void NaitiveDemo.test()'         at NaitiveDemo.test(Native Method)         at NaitiveDemo.main(NaitiveDemo.java:27)

As @ThomasKläger said, the declaration in the generated Main.h file shows the name and 'signature' (attributes and return and parameter types) that JNI requires. You must change your code (Main.cpp) so your native function definition has exactly that name and signature. (You will need to #include jni.h to get the macros and typedefs.) Normally you need to add identifiers for the parameters, but for your intentionally useless test this could be skipped.

following line in my code void test(int var) is in NaitiveDemo.cpp is this line not sufficient and after your suggestion I added #include<jni/h> in my NaitiveDemo.cpp but compiling this gives me error .\NaitiveDemo.cpp:6:10: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory     6 | #include <jni.h>       |          ^~~~~~~ I am using visual studio code to do all this

IMHO you have two questions: the first one was "why does java report Error: Could not find or load main class .library.path=C:..." which was answered in the linked question. Now you have a second question: "how can I implement the native code so that Java can load it?". You should create a second question for that (and link to it in a comment)

But basically what you need are the header files from your Java installation (in a path something like C:\Program Files\Java\21\include)
